# Convert p7s to p12

Tags: ssl, openssl, cryptography, ssl-certificate, certificate

I am trying to convert p7s file to p12 to sign documents in acrobat reader, I am using openssl to convert p7s to pem before convert pem to p12, when I have to convert pem to p12 commonly require a private key, but you can omit it by using the flag  -nokeys, but when I installed certificate in Windows I have the following error: "A system-level error ocurred while verifiyingtrust" and can not use in acrobat. The commands that I use are these:

This is the command to convert p7s to pem:

```
openssl pkcs7 -inform pem -print_certs -in test.p7s -out certificate_test1.pem
```

THis is the command to convert pem to p12 (after put that I have to set a password):

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -nokeys -in certificate_test1.pem -out pkcs12.p12
```

I am doning something wrong or is possible to generate the private keys for the p12 and that must to be valid for windows?

Thanks!!!

Comment: You _can_ make a PFX/PKCS12/p12 file with no private key, but it won't enable you to sign later.  If you don't have a private key already hanging out somewhere, you won't be able to make progress.

Comment: Is possible to generate private keys?

Comment: Not after the fact.  If it was possible, signing would be worthless.  The private key and public key are generated together.  Public keys can usually be created from private ones, but not the other way around.